# Deserialize Generic Class in GSON in Android

Tags: android, gson

I have this class :

```
public class DbReturned<T> {
   public boolean State;
   public int UserID;
   public String Error;
   public T row;
   public List<T> Data;
   public boolean Hr;
   public boolean Credits;
}
```

and Credit class is :

```
public class Credits {
  public int id;
  public int year;
  public int month;
  public double t1;
  public double t2;
  public double t3;
}
```

and JSON is

```
result = {"State":true,"UserID":0,"Error":null,"Data":[{"id":1,"year":2017,"month":1,"t1":77,"t2":88,"t3":99,"CreateBy":1,"CreateDate":"2017-08-22T13:58:27.497","ModifyBy":1,"ModifyDate":"2017-08-22T13:58:27.497"}],"row":null,"Credits":false,"Hr":false}
```

How to deserialize to DbReturned:
this code isn't working :

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
            if(result != null) {
                DbReturned<Credits> data = gson.fromJson(result, DbReturned.class);
            }
```

I used : compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4' in gradle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution :

```
 public <T> DbReturned<T> getResponse(final Class<T> dataClass ,
                                         final String rawResponse) 
    {
        return gson.fromJson(rawResponse, 
                             getType(DbReturned.class, 
                             dataClass));
    }



private Type getType(final Class<?> rawClass, 
                       final Class<?> 
                       parameterClass) 
   {
        return new ParameterizedType() {
            @Override
            public Type[] getActualTypeArguments() {
                return new Type[]{parameterClass};
            }

            @Override
            public Type getRawType() {
                return rawClass;
            }

            @Override
            public Type getOwnerType() {
                return null;
            }

        };
    }
```

and  i called it :

```
DbReturned<Credits> data = getResponse(Credits.class , 
                                       result.toString());
```

and the Gson variable is final at top of class :

```
public  final  Gson gson = new Gson();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
DbReturned<Credits> data = gson.fromJson(result, new DbReturned<Credits>(){}.getType());
```

to declare full data type for GSON.